# How can we copy or move a image/file using Sails js or Node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, sails.js

My Requirement is to copy files/ image from a existing folder to another folder. How can i achieve it using SAILS JS
I tried with this :

```js
    var imagePath = photoName;  //image source path 
    var proImagePath = './assets/images/profilePics/'; //image destination

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(imagePath);
    stream.on('error', function (error) 
 {
  console.log("Caught", error);
 });
    stream.on('readable', function ()
 {
  stream.read();
  var desti = fs.createWriteStream(proImagePath);  //desti
  stream.pipe(desti);
  stream.on('end',function() {
        stream.close();
   return res.json(200, {status: 1, message: 'Success.'});
 });
```

But consoling an error with :

```js
  Caught { [Error: ENOENT, open 'http://192.168.1.64:9002/images/userimages/sijobhai/91121438-7219-4c0f-b27c-516b289614a2.jpg']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'http://192.168.1.64:9002/images/userimages/sijobhai/91121438-7219-4c0f-b27c-516b289614a2.jpg' }
```

Comment: take a look at node fs  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Doesn't appear that you even attempted a web search for this. You are expected to do basic research before asking questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//use this code

```
var fs = require('fs');

var source = fs.createReadStream('source_file_path');
var desti = fs.createWriteStream('destination_file_path');

source.pipe(desti);
source.on('end',function() {

   source.close();
   //if you want to delete file fron origin.
   fs.unlink(source_file_path);


});
```

Comment: i tries it earlier but showed me an error:
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open

Comment: THE PATH CONSOLED IN TERMINAL IS CORRECTLY OPENING IN THE BROWSER

Comment: are u using ubontu

Comment: yes..using ubuntu and running my application via terminal

Comment: run sails server as root

Comment: yes i did it @manoj..
now i have fixed the reading of file but stuck in writing, that file which we have read should be saved right.
Error: EISDIR, open '/var/www/html/zentiera/assets/images/profilePics/'


i also tried with a dummy file /var/www/html/zentiera/assets/images/profilePics/abc.jpg'

its only creating a empty file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113635/discussion-between-vishnu-s-babu-and-manoj-ojha).